# Making a progressbar to load from 0 to 100% in 10 seconds with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a simple progressbar to load for 10 seconds always when the JavaScript function is called. I don't want to use jQuery or any library. I want it to be on clean JavaScript. The only think I don't understand is how to make the progressbar load from 0 to 100% in 10 seconds. I am providing code with what I have done until now. Any suggestions?

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("slide-progress-bar");
var width = 1;

function progressBar() {
  resetProgressBar();

  id = setInterval(frame, 100);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}

function resetProgressBar() {
  width = 1;
  elem.style.width = width + '%';
}
```

```css
.slide-progress-bar {
  width: 1118px;
  background-color: rgba(155, 155, 255, 0.36);
  transition: width 10s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #aff;
  width: 1%;
  position: relative;
  transition: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar"></div>
  <!--progress-bar-->
</div>
<!--slide-progress-bar-->
```

Comment: It seems to be invisible... - I made you a snippet and changed the colours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to change the element that you are increasing in width. Not sure if this is the behaviour you expected:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
var width = 1;
var interval;

function progressBar() {
  resetProgressBar();

  interval = setInterval(frame, 100);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}

function resetProgressBar() {
  width = 1;
  clearInterval(interval)
  elem.style.width = width + '%';
}
```

```css
.slide-progress-bar {
  width: 1118px;
  background-color: rgba(155, 155, 255, 0.36);
  transition: width 10s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #aff;
  width: 1%;
  position: relative;
  transition: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar"></div>
  <!--progress-bar-->
</div>
<button onclick="progressBar()">Start</button>
<!--slide-progress-bar-->
```

Comment: Do you know why if I keep clicking the Start button to restart the progressbar, the progressbar loads faster and faster ?

Comment: I just updated the answer. The problem was that it only cleared the interval when it reached the max width. By clicking the "Start" button, several intervals were stacked. It can be easily solved by clearing the interval each time you call "resetProgressbar()"

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

I changed the elem to the inner div and removed the width from the CSS

I also changed the speed

Then I actually called the function

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
var width = 1;

function progressBar() {
  resetProgressBar();

  id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width +"%";
    }
  }
}
function resetProgressBar() {
  width = 1;
  elem.style.width = width;
}
progressBar()
```

```css
.slide-progress-bar {
  width: 1118px;
  background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.36);
  transition: width 10s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #aff;
  position: relative;
  transition: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar"></div>
  <!--progress-bar-->
</div>
<!--slide-progress-bar-->
```

Answer (score 0):

as far I understood I think you are looking for this. the progress-bar will be completed 100% after 10s

```js
 var elem = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
    var width = 1;

    function progressBar() {
        resetProgressBar();

        id = setInterval(frame, 1000);

        function frame() {
            if (width >= 100) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                width+=10;
                elem.style.width = width + '%';
            }
        }
    }

   

    function resetProgressBar() {
        width = 1;
        elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
    
     progressBar();
```

```css
.slide-progress-bar {
            width: 1118px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.36);
            transition: width 10s linear;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .progress-bar {
            height: 5px;
            background-color: #fff2ff;
            width: 1%;
            position: relative;
            transition: linear;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="slide-progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar"></div>
        <!--progress-bar-->
 </div>
```

let me know if it`s not ok

Comment: Looks better to change the speed like I did

Answer (score 0):

HI please check below solution

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
var width = 1;
var id = {};

function progressBar() {

  id = setInterval(frame, 100);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}

progressBar()
```

```css
.slide-progress-bar {
  width: 1118px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  transition: width 10s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  transition: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar"></div>
  <!--progress-bar-->
</div>
<!--slide-progress-bar-->
```

Comment: I have a quick question. I made the function to be called when a button is clicked. The reset resetProgressBar() function is called at the starting of the progressbar() function. So everytime when I click the button, the progressbar starts loading, BUT he loads faster and faster. What makes the progressbar loads much faster with every click ( call ) of the function?